# SSRS Row Count of detail groups for EACH page

Tags: reporting-services

How do I count the number of detail rows on EACH PAGE and make sure that the row count is reset on each page? For example, if I have 6 detail rows in the first page and 3 detail rows in the second page, I would like to display as "Page Record Count: 6" on the first page and "Page Record Count:3" on the second page. So far, I have tried  `CountRows("DetailGroupName")` but it gives the cumulative row counts so right now I get "Page Record Count:6" on the first page and "Page Record Count:9" on the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can't count row of dataset on the page, but you can count report items on the page. However, this should work only for page header/footer.
You need to add textbox in page header f.e., and count report items on the page.
[image]